# Getting run time error working with vectors

Tags: c++

So, I read the problem 4.5 from Accelerated C++, and interpreted it rather wrong. I wrote a program which is supposed to display counts of a word in string. However, I have probably done something very stupid, and very wrong. I can't figure it out.

Here's the code: http://ideone.com/87zA7E.

Stackoverflow says links to ideone.com must be accompanied by code. Instead of pasting the all of it, I will just paste the function which I think is most likely at fault:

```
vector<str_info> words(const vector<string>& s) {

vector<str_info> rex;
str_info record;

typedef vector<string>::size_type str_sz;
str_sz i = 0;

while (i != s.size()) {
    record.str = s[i];
    record.count = 0;
    ++i; //edit

    for (str_sz j = 0; j != s.size(); ++j) {
        if (compare(record, s[j]))
            ++record.count;
    }

    for (vector<str_info>::size_type k = 0; k != s.size(); ++k) {
        if (!compare(record, rex[k].str))
            rex.push_back(record);
    }
}

return rex;
}
```

Comment: Where's the problem? What does it do?

Comment: It's run time error. Last time I ran it on my computer, it ate all RAM. However, even after incrementing the 'i', I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have this:

```
str_sz i = 0;

while (i != s.size()) {
```

but you never increment `i`, leading to an endless loop. Inside of that loop, you're pushing elements into vector `rex`. A vector cannot contain an infinite number of elements.

Comment: Oh, god, I am so stupid. Of course! And now I feel so embarrassed. Sorry.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem. I think I have used the loops totally wrong. Do you think you have a better alternative solution, that is assuming you understand what I was trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you are trying to access:

```
rex[k].str
```

in

```
for (vector<str_info>::size_type k = 0; k != s.size(); ++k) {
        if (!compare(record, rex[k].str)) // rex is empty in the beginning!!
            rex.push_back(record);
    }
```

But you do not know whether rex has k+1 elements in it.

EDIT: Change your code to:

```
while (i != s.size()) {

    // read new string into a record (initial count should be one).
    str_info record;
    record.str = s[i];
    record.count = 1;

    // check if this string already exists in rex
    bool found = false;
    for (vector<str_info>::size_type k = 0; k < rex.size(); ++k) {
        if ( record.str == rex[k].str ) {
            rex[k].count++;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }


    i++;        
    if ( found )
       continue;

    // if it is not found then push_back to rex
    rex.push_back( record );
}
```

Comment: Do you think if I replace s.size() with rex.size() it would work?

Comment: @user35846 Then it will never enter the for loop.

Comment: @user35846 Please tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry. My program (is supposed to) print(s) words and their count(no. of appearance) in a string.